# SQL server query help - only show particular results after 90 days

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT
   Year(comm_date_utc) as Year, 
   Month(comm_date_utc) as Month, 
   owner_agent_login, 
   COUNT(comm_id)as Correspondences_count, 
   location 
FROM
   Correspondences
LEFT JOIN
   Agents a ON owner_agent_login = agent_login_id
WHERE
   location in ('AUS', 'USA', 'SA', 'IRE')
   AND comm_date_utc between '2012/11/01 12:47:00' and '2013/9/30 23:59:00'
   AND start_date < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, '2013/9/30 23:59:00') - 90, 0)
GROUP BY 
   Year(comm_date_utc), Month(comm_date_utc), location, owner_agent_login
```

Its giving me results showing me each agent and how many items they have done broken down into months.

IF I change the end date which is these 2 items:

```
 AND '2013/9/30 23:59:00'
 AND start_date < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, '2013/9/30 23:59:00') - 90, 0)
```

What is happening is that because the end date is NOT showing any results for an employee that has started within the last 90 days, which works well. BUT when someone has been on for more than 90 days it then show all of the employees results, what I need this to actually do is say on 90 days show ONLY the last month, not the last 3 months. So to best articulate this from data here is what it might look like:

If I ran the query and the user login3 start date has been longer than 90 days it will show ALL of his results like so.

```
Year    Month   owner_agent_login   Correspondences_count   location
2013    1   Login1                      180 IRE
2013    2   Login1                  209 IRE
2013    3   Login1                  208 IRE
2013    4   Login1                  189 IRE
2013    5   Login1                  191 IRE
2013    1   Login2                  140 USA
2013    2   Login2                  103 USA
2013    3   Login2                  137 USA
2013    4   Login2                  156 USA   
2013    5   Login2                  183 USA
2013    3   Login3                  30  USA
2013    4   Login3                  76  AUS
2013    5   Login3                  98  AUS
```

What I need it to do is show only the results after the 90 days, so the other results would be NOT counted. it would look like this:

```
Year    Month   owner_agent_login   Correspondences_count   location

2013    1   Login1                           180              IRE
2013    2   Login1                           209              IRE
2013    3   Login1                           208              IRE
2013    4   Login1                           189          IRE
2013    5   Login1                           191              IRE
2013    1   Login2                           140              USA
2013    2   Login2                           103              USA
2013    3   Login2                           137              USA
2013    4   Login2                           156              USA
2013    5   Login2                           183              USA
2013    5   Login3                            12              AUS
```

NOTE the last login3 only has now 1 result with a smaller number, this is what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was an easy correction, I just needed stop over complicating it. just change this:

```
AND start_date < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, '2013/9/30 23:59:00') - 90, 0)
```

to:

```
 and comm_date_utc between DATEADD(MONTH,3,start_date) and '2013/10/31 23:59:00'
```